# MySQL UTF Text Capacity

Tags: mysql, unicode, tinytext

I have column named "summary" (tinytext, utf8_turkish_ci). I know it can store 255 byte also 255 chars. But if i use unicode chars like Ç, Ö, Ü storage capacitiy naturally decreasing. If my visitor enter 250 chars long unicode text then last chars are erasing. My summary column will be always 250 chars long. What can i do ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could turn it into a `varchar` instead. The length of a `varchar` is limited to the number of *characters* you specify. The length of a `tinytext` field is limited to 255 *bytes*.

Comment: An additional note: In MySQL 5, Innodb will only allow a key of 767 bytes, though fields that are not part of a key may be longer. Since the OP is using a utf8 character set and MySQL uses 3 bytes per character, a `varchar` field in a key will have a limit of 255.67 characters, which in practice means a maximum of 255 characters. As the OP only needs 250 chars, this should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is variable length encoding. A char can be encoded into 1 to 4 bytes (theoretically limit is 6 but I haven't encountered it yet). If you are dealing with Turkish only, only 2 bytes is needed for each char. So you will need a column size of 500 bytes to support 250 chars so you should use something like `varchar(500)` or `text`.